# Present Value of a Perpetuity

Tags: interest-rate

I have a very basic understanding of Present Value of a Perpetuity.

**Present value = Amount / interest**

I have 2 questions below:

(a) Suppose that the annual interest rate is 10%. What is the value of a perpetuity that pays $30 every year from the beginning of next year?

(b) Suppose that the annual interest rate is 5%. What is the value of a perpetuity that pays $100 every other year from the beginning of next year?

According to the formula:

(a) PV = 30 / 0.1 = $300 and
(b) PV = 100 / 0.5 = $200

But the questions have "beginning of next year"? what does this mean? How can I calculate the value of a perpetuity of these 2 questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to a) is correct: `PV = 30 / 0.1 = $300`

"*from the beginning of next year*" means start with $300, wait a year over which time $30 interest accrues, then withdraw it, starting again at $300.

For b) use a two-year period, so use `r = (1 + 0.05)^2 - 1 = 0.1025`

However, the first withdrawal should happen after one year,

so adjust the two-year cycle to start with `x = PV (1 + 0.05) - 100`

Now `x = 100/0.1025`

and `PV = (x + 100)/(1 + 0.05) = 1024.39`